# Where can I place attributes that need to be accessible from all cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

Is there some place where I can put all common attributes/properties.? Maybe `solo.rb`?

`-j json` is not applicable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer really depends on what kind of attribute it is.

For example you could set a common global attribute in a:

- Environment
- Role
- Cookbook included by all other cookbooks

An exotic alternative would be to use a databag, another useful way to record global data.

Example use-cases:

- Store truly global information (stuff that never changes) in an Environment. This enables you to later create logically groupings of VMs with slight different global defaults.
- For common attributes that rarely change consider a common cookbook, instead of a role. Roles cannot be versioned a feature that might be useful if you later want to support Dev/Test/Prod environments.
- Databags are most useful when used to "data drive" a cookbook. I use them to generate resources, such as projects and other types of entity in my system.

Comment: I know this is old, but I think a common ("base") cookbook is great, even if the attribute never changes. 

In my scenario, we have our cookbooks in source control (duh), and their uploads and other management automated. We didn't have our environment in source control, or automated. And our Chef Server crashed. We knew this was a problem, but didn't worry about it. So, if we put them in a cookbook, we get to use the same automation patterns we already have established. Sure we can put an environment in source control and automate that, but cookbook just seems easier.

Comment: @JasonCapriotti You're describing an application cookbook pattern, which is quite legitimate as one can use Berkshelf to download dependencies like a "base" cookbook. Environments can still be used to complement this solution, enabling you to override the settings that you default in the cookbooks. For lots more information I suggest the following read: http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a common cookbook.

Comment: Should I add dependency in `metadata.rb` for this common cookbook?